# loop + slice/split np array and store to another array

Tags: python, arrays, loops

i am basically new to python and tried my first selenium project. I've learned a lot through this board, but i can't find a solution for my current problem. I got an array from reading an excel sheet that looks like this:

```
order number    customer name   customer no.    article
48000100    supplierx   1           article1
48000101    suppliery   2           article2
48000101    suppliery   2           article3
48000102    supplierz   3           article4
```

```
list = np.array([["48000100","48000101","48000101","48000102"],
                 ["supplierx","suppliery","suppliery","supplierz"],
                 ["1","2","2","3"],
                 ["article1", "article2", "article3", "article4"]])
```

The data is already sorted by order number.
I would like to loop through the array and split it up based on the order numbers and write it to another array.

For ex.:

after the first loop second array should look like:

```
[["48000100"],
["supplierx"],
["1"],
["article1"]]

second loop:
[["48000101","48000101"],
["suppliery","suppliery"],
["2","2"],
["article2", "article3"]]

last loop:
[["48000102"],
["supplierz"],
["3"],
["article4"]]
```

I've tried a few things, but i couldnt find a solution.
Many thanks for your help.

Edit: I might figuered out how to solve my problem. Here is the code I used:

```
loop_counter = 0
list1 = np.array([["48000100","48000101","48000101","48000102"],
                   ["supplierx","suppliery","suppliery","supplierz"],
                   ["1","2","2","3"],
                   ["article1", "article2", "article3", "article4"]])

list2 = []
list_of_lists = np.array([])

# selenium calls website
current_pos_arr = 0
count_same_orders = 1
while current_pos_arr <= (len(list1[0])-1):
    if current_pos_arr != (len(list1[0])-1):
        if list1[0][current_pos_arr+1] == list1[0][current_pos_arr]:
            count_same_orders = current_pos_arr + 1
        else:
            count_same_orders = current_pos_arr
    else:
        count_same_orders = current_pos_arr
    list2 = list1[0:len(list1), current_pos_arr:count_same_orders+1]
    print(list2)
    
    # some other code
    # start sending splitted sequence to SAP front page
    # insert supplier name from splitted array - list2
    # check order numbers and do some stuff
    # when finished, the webdriver is directed to the front page 

    # loop to get next split and send next sequence of array
    current_pos_arr = count_same_orders + 1
```

I first tried to use np.delete to separate the array by the axis, but I couldn't cast the deleted column into another array. Then I came to this solution. Short explanation: I can send only one sequence at a time from my first array to a webpage. Each order number represents a sequence.
After the selenium driver finished its work, the driver will be directed to the front page and the program sends the next sequence of the array. That’s why I need a loop instead of an one-liner.
If someone has a better idea or a better code, please feel free to post it here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some pandas groupby to solve this issue.

```
arr = np.array([["48000100","48000101","48000101","48000102"],
                 ["supplierx","suppliery","suppliery","supplierz"],
                 ["1","2","2","3"],
                 ["article1", "article2", "article3", "article4"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(arr.T, columns=['order number', 'customer name', 'customer no.', 'article'])
```

```
list_of_lists = df.groupby('order number', as_index=False).agg(list).to_numpy().tolist()
print(list_of_lists)
```

```
[
    [
        '48000100', 
        ['supplierx'], 
        ['1'], 
        ['article1']
    ],
    [
        '48000101', 
        ['suppliery', 'suppliery'],
        ['2', '2'], ['article2', 'article3']
    ], 
    [
        '48000102', 
        ['supplierz'],
        ['3'],
        ['article4']
    ]
]
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it wasnt exactly what i was looking for. I did some edits, on my post, so feel free to check it out.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if I understand your task, but if you have list1 to start with, use my code to calculate my `list_of_lists` and then iterate over it, then you have your different arrays in each step of the iteration and use it.